# What isometric Android game with trucks and houses is this?

Tags: android, game-identification

This is a screenshot of an android game. Can anyone tell me what the name of this game is?

[image: cartoonish isometric game with houses and trucks]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an Android/iPhone game called [Splash Cars](https://www.craneballs.com/games/splash-cars-31.html).

There aren't a lot of screen shots on the site above, but a Google Image search shows more: [Google Image Search: Splash Cars](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=%22splash%20cars%22)